# How to access datagroup's Itemrenederer's component?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a datagroup where I use a custom itemRenderer with a datagrid inside. What I want is to access each datagroup's itemRenderer's datagrid and get it's dataProvider

All I know is that you can access the ItemRenderer by using myDataGroup.getElementAt(index)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you need to do this.  Wouldn't your dataGroup already have access to all the data it is passing down into the renderers?

That said something like this should work:

```
(myDataGroup.getElementAt(index) as myCustomItemRenderer).myDataGrid.dataProvider
```

Comment: Well I want to get the edited dataProvider from each itemRenderer's datagrid

Comment: Can you quantify what "edited" means in this case?  Objects are passed by reference, so if the dataProvider is modified in your renderer it should automatically be updated in the parent.

Comment: What I actually want to do is to loop through all the datagrids calculate their total values and the display the sum of all totals.